# Problem inserting binary data through SQL query (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert, binary-data, varbinarymax

These is the query i have found for inserting binary data (using varbinary) which is working perfectly

`CREATE TABLE Employees
(

    Id int,

    Name varchar(50) not null,

    Photo varbinary(max) not null

)`

`INSERT INTO Employees (Id, Name, Photo)

SELECT 10, 'John', BulkColumn from Openrowset( Bulk 'C:\photo.bmp', Single_Blob) as EmployeePicture`

**But what if the table employee has columns like:**

`CREATE TABLE Employees
(

    Id int,

    Photo varbinary(max) not null,

    Name varchar(50) not null

)`

*[Photo column is 2nd over here!]*
I tried manipulating the insert query but didnt help!!

Comment: Show us what queries you tried.  And did you try just using the query as-is?  Since you are using the variant of `INSERT INTO` that lists column names, it shouldn't matter what order the columns are in vs. their order in the actual table -- that's the point of using column names -- not having to worry about their order in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use

```
 INSERT INTO Employees
 SELECT 10, BulkColumn AS EmployeePicture, 'John'
 FROM OPENROWSET( BULK 'C:\photo.bmp', Single_Blob) bc
```

Or

```
 INSERT INTO Employees
 SELECT 10, 
        (SELECT BulkColumn AS EmployeePicture  FROM OPENROWSET( BULK 'C:\photo.bmp', Single_Blob) bc), 
        'John'
```

I presume you were probably trying something like this

```
 INSERT INTO Employees
 SELECT 10, 
        BulkColumn AS EmployeePicture  FROM OPENROWSET( BULK 'C:\photo.bmp', Single_Blob), 
        'John'
```

Comment: You are right Martin!! This is one of the 7 to 8 queries i tried. :)  I would be using the second query as it is logically sound and multiple binary data can be easily inserted through it.  Are there any online resources where i can study and understand the syntax of these queries? I know the basics of SQL which are provided on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com) but complex queries such as these are hard to find.  BTW which formatting did u use for displaying queries?

Comment: To format the query as code in StackOverflow you select the text to be formatted as code and hit the code icon `{}`. Not really sure about online resources. Joe Celko's SQL for Smarties is definitely worth a read though.

Comment: Thanks again Martin.   I got the book, will definitely gain something from it.